# Border-Color on table refuses to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something oh so simple, apply a border color to a table, as well as a small radius, like so:

```
.myTable {
    border: 1px solid #b6dde3;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine in isolation, but in a Twitter Bootstrap project no matter what I do, the appearance does not change, it just looks as though no styling has been applied to it all!

All of my other CSS works normally.

Is this normal Bootstrap behaviour? How do I override it?

Thanks

Comment: Seems fine in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v5KAa/. Is your styling coming before or after Bootstrap's?

Comment: @j08691 Updated my question, seems to be Twitter Bootstrap specific.

Comment: Try adding !important after your border style.  see: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using BS 3.1.1, you'll need to add an additional property to CSS, as shown below (based off what you've given):

```
.myTable {
    border: 1px solid #b6dde3;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px; /* IE9+ supports border-radius, no need to prefix */
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-collapse: separate; /* add this */
}
```

**[View Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6UC6D/2/)**

Comment: Thankyou so much, you just saved my Laptop from going through the window!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you feel the answer above solved your issue, please accept it so others will have a better idea in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/39Z5k/, it works perfectly by itself, so the bootstrap is probably just overwriting your rules.

```
.myTable {
    border: 1px solid #b6dde3;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I tell Bootstrap to back off? Nothing is working, not even !important